# Determining valid input to this function

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, physics

I've written an algorithm, the details of which I think are irrelevant here, which accomplishes the following task:

Suppose we're given three observers in a 2-dimensional plane (such that the three observers do not form a line), the velocity of some signal, and the time at which each observer received the signal. I want to reconstruct the coordinates of the source.

One issue I ran into was sanitizing the input. I did *not* want the algorithm to attempt reconstructing sources that did not represent a reasonable facsimile of a signal in two dimensions. For example, the time differences that correspond to a source above the receivers in three dimensional space should be tossed out.

I was eventually able to do so fairly easily. I started by throwing out all time differences greater than the maximum possible (which happens to be a source stationed at one of the three observers), and time differences less than the minimum possible (a source at the incenter of the three observers).

Now, I'm expanding the algorithm to *three* dimensions. Again, I'm throwing out all input with time differences greater than the maximum, or less than the minimum, possible. I'm not sure, however, if there are other combinations of time differences that do not correspond to solutions in 3-dimensional space.

With the 2d solution, I tossed out every time difference corresponding to a source in 3d space (i.e. one not coplanar with the three observers). Are there time differences in '4d' space that I should be throwing out in my 3d solution?

*Note: please feel free to rename/retag. I'm not sure precisely what sort of problem this is.*

Comment: Sorry, but even in 2D, you should be more explicit. It does not look to be what is called a goniometric issue (do you know this term ?) with a maximum intensity in the direction of emission (in this case two obervers are enough). I think here, observers have a common reference time, and take into account the $\Delta t$ in reception ? .

Comment: @JeanMarie Hi. Thanks for the comment. Yes, I'm familiar with the term, but I'm not sure I understand your point?

Comment: My point : Can you say first that it is not goniometry ?  Then that it is my second interpretation : 3  observers placed at the vertices of a triangle and  listen a same thunder strike at 1s, 2s and 4s, by reference to a same time base : they are able to find the place. Is that what you mean ? But for 3D you need a 4th observer...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, that's right. In 2d, three observers in a triangle "listen to the same thunder strike", where all three observers have synchronized clocks, and we use the time differences to determine the coordinates of the source. In 3d, it's more or less the same thing, but with 4 observers.